# object/mesh displacement in OSL script

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, displacement, osl

I am trying to use an OSL shader to displace the verticies in a fish model to make the fish appear as though it is moving. This should be doable using a vertex shader, but I am new to blender and am unsure if this is possible through the cycles render node editor. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! Most displacement I have been seeing involves texture displacement.